# Issue with adding Column to a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below code fails with AnalysisException: sc.version String = 1.6.0

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
val caseClassDF = Seq(Person("Andy", 32)).toDF()
caseClassDF.count()

val seq = Seq(1)
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(seq)
val df2 = rdd.toDF("Counts")
df2.count()

val withCounts = caseClassDF.withColumn("duration", df2("Counts"))
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, it works with UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
case class Person(name: String, age: Long, day: Int)
val caseClassDF = Seq(Person("Andy", 32, 1), Person("Raman", 22, 1), Person("Rajan", 40, 1), Person("Andy", 42, 2), Person("Raman", 42, 2), Person("Rajan", 50, 2)).toDF()

val calculateCounts= udf((x: Long, y: Int) => 
  x+y)

val df1 = caseClassDF.withColumn("Counts", calculateCounts($"age", $"day"))
df1.show

+-----+---+---+------+
| name|age|day|Counts|
+-----+---+---+------+
| Andy| 32|  1|    33|
|Raman| 22|  1|    23|
|Rajan| 40|  1|    41|
| Andy| 42|  2|    44|
|Raman| 42|  2|    44|
|Rajan| 50|  2|    52|
+-----+---+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

caseClassDF.withColumn("duration", **df2("Counts")**), Here the column should be of the same dataframe (in your case *caseClassDF*). AFAIK, Spark does not allow column of a different DataFrame in withColumn.

PS: I am a user of Spark 1.6.x, not sure whether this has come up in Spark 2.x

Comment: Thanks Rishabh. Updated the Spark version. I am not convinced that Column should be from the same dataframe.